# jsPDF Multipage PDF - page breaking inappropriately

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I have a complex html derived from a word document which is need to converted to pdf. I converted the table into image using html2canvas, I have added that html converted image to the empty pdf using jsPDF's addImage function.Everything is working fine. But while breaking the image to multiple PDF pages its breaking inappropriately in sense a table row which has border starts in page 1 ending and ends in page 2 beginning as shown in the image below.

[image]

Tried few things but it dint worked much.Below is my code.

```
    var quotes = document.getElementById('totable');
    //! MAKE YOUR PDF
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    html2canvas(quotes, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {



            for (var i = 0; i <= quotes.clientHeight / 980; i++) {
                //! This is all just html2canvas stuff
                var srcImg = canvas;
                var sX = 0;
                var sY = 1100 * i; // start 1100 pixels down for every new page
                var sWidth = 900;
                var sHeight = 1100;
                var dX = 0;
                var dY = 0;
                var dWidth = 900;
                var dHeight = 1100;

                window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', 900);
                onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', 1100);
                var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
                // details on this usage of this function: 
                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Slicing
                ctx.drawImage(srcImg, sX, sY, sWidth, sHeight, dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight);

                // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

                var width = onePageCanvas.width;
                var height = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;

                //! If we're on anything other than the first page,
                // add another page
                if (i > 0) {
                    pdf.addPage(612, 791); //8.5" x 11" in pts (in*72)
                }
                //! now we declare that we're working on that page
                pdf.setPage(i + 1);
                //! now we add content to that page!
                pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', 20, 40, (width * .62), (height * .62));

            }
        }
    })
```

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MbQI0Y?p=preview) as well. Any suggestion how to achieve proper splitting into multiple pages?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I am currently having the same issue , how did you solve yours ? You can answer your questions btw.